# In Flyway, is skipExecutingMigrations available on current Community Edition for use in Java?

Tags: flyway

The documentation implies it is:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/configuration/parameters/flyway/skip-executing-migrations

unlike CherryPick which is in Team edition.
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/cherry-pick-224919700.html

I am using version 10.9.1 of Community.

I cannot get it to work; all migrations are attempted to run despite the setting.

Looking thru Flyway source code, I do not see it being checked when performing migrations.  I am setting it in my java code:

flywayConfig.skipExecutingMigrations(true);

Answer (score 1):

This isn't (currently) in the open source package so we'll get the page updated. We've been moving things out of Teams and some things into OSS and the docs sometimes fall out of sync. To get this working, you'll need to get the flyway-core dependency from the Redgate repository as described here: https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/api-java-184127629.html